# Math with datetime in SQL query in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

So I have an table of `phone_numbers` in Rails 3.2, and I would like to be able to make a query such as the following:

```
PhoneNumber.where("last_called_at - #{Time.now} > call_spacing * 60")
```

where last_called_at is a `datetime` and `call_spacing` is an integer, representing the number of minutes between calls.

I have tried the above, I have also tried using

```
PhoneNumber.where("datediff(mi, last_called_at, #{Time.now}) > call_spacing")
```

If anyone could help me make this work, or even recommend a current, up-to-date rails SQL gem, I would be very grateful.

Edit: So the best way to make this work for me was to instead add a `ready_at` column to my database, and update that whenever either `call_spacing` or `last_called_at` was updated, using the `before_save` method. This is probably the most semantic way to approach this problem in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use quotes around #{Time.now}. To make your first query work you may use TIME_TO_SEC() function:

```
PhoneNumber.where("(TIME_TO_SEC('#{Time.now}') - TIME_TO_SEC(last_called_at)) > (call_spacing * 60)")
```

Here is my way to do this:

```
PhoneNumber.where("last_called_at > '#{Time.zone.now.utc - (call_spacing * 60)}'")
```

also take a look at this article to be aware of how to play with timezones:

http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/

Comment: Ok, I think this is on the right track, but part of the problem with this query is that `call_spacing` is not a local variable, its a database column.

Comment: As long as you want to compare it with call_spacing which is an integer value you may use TIME_TO_SEC for those dates and then make calculations using seconds. Please look again at first query in my answer. It should be a good way to go. Is there somethig more to do than specified problem?